# Dynamic A to Z content list in jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, dynamic-sql

I'm looking to build an A to Z content list in jQuery Mobile where data is read and grouped dynamically. Is this possible?

I want something like this grouped dynamically from their documentation (which is static):http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/#docs/lists/lists-divider.html

But what would be really awesome is if I could get the grouping to be with collapsible content...

Any thoughts, examples, or resources out there?

Comment: Just install click handler to dividers yourself and make them perform show/hide of list elements?

Comment: @mikko Can you expand on your thought? So are you referencing that the list dividers themselves are not dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

A list divider is itself a list item in jQuery mobile. You'd probably need to do it by hand (insert things into the list alphabetically and put in a list divider `<li>` for each letter). And yeah, put click handlers on the list dividers to make them show and hide all the `<li>` s under them. So you're aiming for a list structure like:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-theme="g">
    <li data-role="list-divider">A</li>
    <li class="a"><a href="acura.html">Acura</a></li>
    <li class="a"><a href="audi.html">Audi</a></li>
    <li data-role="list-divider">B</li>
    <li class="b"><a href="bmw.html">BMW</a></li>
</ul>
```

And then attach a click handler on the list divider for A to make it hide all `<li>`s with the class "a". But you will have to generate it by hand, till someone writes a plugin to convert an object into a JQM list, if it doesn't exist already.

Comment: Thank you Jayraj. I found an alternative direction for this project, but I appreciate your help. I hope to jump back into this troubleshooting sometime down the road.